# Was Michael Eddington's development worked out from the time of his initial introduction?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, character-development

Initially, he is

> a minor antagonist to Odo and Sisko to demonstrate Starfleet questioning of Odo's loyalty

But of course, I'm referring to his

> eventual defection to the Maquis and acting as a major antagonist to Sisko (at least for several episodes)

Comment: Memory Alpha has some well sourced information in the [Background Information](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Michael_Eddington#Background_information) section for whoever cares to answer. *"When he was first cast as Eddington, neither Marshall nor the writer-producers were certain about how the character would develop."*

Comment: He's one of my favorite secondary characters in DS9 as he was a really well developed character.

Answer (score 8):

**No**

According to [Ronald D. Moore](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Ronald_D._Moore) in a 1997 AOL chat:

> *'I am curious if you decided from the start to make Eddington a "bad" guy, or if was just a good story.  The same goes for Kasidy'*
>
> "Neither character was developed initially with their Maquis
>   affiliation in mind.  The Kasidy connection came first and was pitched
>   to us by a free-lance writer.  During the development of that
>   storyline, we came up with the Eddington angle."

https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Memory_Alpha:AOL_chats/Ronald_D._Moore/ron012.txt